# Get None the values with scrapy

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I have a problem while trying to scrape a page.

I don't get any errors, but it also doesn't bring me the correct data. Instead it returns `None`.

`{'rank': None, 'player': None, 'team': None, 'ranking_value': None}`.

When I use browser dev tools and search for the xpath, I can view the elements.

I attach the code

```
import scrapy
class Prueba02Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "prueba02"
    allowed_domains = ["one-versus-one.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://one-versus-one.com/es/rankings/todos/estad%C3%ADstica?model=1v1_index&page=1&age_min=16&age_max=40&total_id=total"]

    def parse(self, response):
        for i in response.xpath('.//div[@class="ranking-section__list-item-rank"]'):
            rank = i.xpath('//a/div[@class="ranking-section__list-item-rank"]/text()').get()
            player = i.xpath('//a/div[@class="ranking-section__list-info-name"]/text()').get()
            team = i.xpath('//a/div[@class="ranking-section__list-item-info-team-name"]/text()').get()
            ranking_value = i.xpath('//div[@class="ranking-section__list-item-info-index-value"]/text()').get()


            yield {
                'rank': rank,
                'player': player,
                'team': team,
                'ranking_value': ranking_value
            }
```

I also need to be able to paginate since it has a button element and the next page has it in the data-page

I already tried to do it with `css` but since I don't have a good experience I couldn't do it, it's for a practical job at the university if you could help me.

Answer (score 0):

The information you are trying to scrape is loaded dynamically, which means it is not contained in the initial response html.  The site does have an API you can access through the url `"https://one-versus-one.com/new-rankings-data?model=1v1_index&page=1&age_min=16&age_max=40"`.  Using the json api you can successfully extract all of the same information.

For pagination you can simply iterate over the page numbers and input the correct page number into it's appropriate place for each request url.

For example:

```
import scrapy


class Prueba02Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "prueba02"
    allowed_domains = ["one-versus-one.com"]

    def start_requests(self):
        for i in range(1, 10):
            url = f"https://one-versus-one.com/new-rankings-data?model=1v1_index&page={i}&age_min=16&age_max=40"
            yield scrapy.Request(url)

    def parse(self, response):
        data = response.json()
        for row in data["data"]:
            yield dict(
                player = row["name"],
                rank = row["rank_in_all_leagues"],
                team = row["team_name"],
                ranking_value = row["value"])
```

OUTPUTS

```
{'player': 'Karim Benzema', 'rank': 11, 'team': 'Real Madrid', 'ranking_value': 94}
2023-02-23 18:25:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://one-versus-one.com/new-rankings-data?model=1v1_index&page=2&age_min=16&age_max=40>
{'player': 'Bruno Fernandes', 'rank': 12, 'team': 'Manchester United', 'ranking_value': 94}
2023-02-23 18:25:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://one-versus-one.com/new-rankings-data?model=1v1_index&page=2&age_min=16&age_max=40>
{'player': 'Leon Goretzka', 'rank': 13, 'team': 'Bayern Munich', 'ranking_value': 94}
2023-02-23 18:25:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://one-versus-one.com/new-rankings-data?model=1v1_index&page=2&age_min=16&age_max=40>
{'player': 'Leroy Sane', 'rank': 14, 'team': 'Bayern Munich', 'ranking_value': 94}
2023-02-23 18:25:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://one-versus-one.com/new-rankings-data?model=1v1_index&page=2&age_min=16&age_max=40>
{'player': 'Jose Diogo Dalot Teixeira', 'rank': 15, 'team': 'Manchester United', 'ranking_value': 94}
2023-02-23 18:25:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://one-versus-one.com/new-rankings-data?model=1v1_index&page=2&age_min=16&age_max=40>
{'player': 'Gabriel Magalhaes', 'rank': 16, 'team': 'Arsenal FC', 'ranking_value': 94}
2023-02-23 18:25:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://one-versus-one.com/new-rankings-data?model=1v1_index&page=2&age_min=16&age_max=40>
{'player': 'Frenkie De Jong', 'rank': 17, 'team': 'Barcelona', 'ranking_value': 94}
2023-02-23 18:25:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://one-versus-one.com/new-rankings-data?model=1v1_index&page=2&age_min=16&age_max=40>
{'player': 'Vinicius Junior', 'rank': 18, 'team': 'Real Madrid', 'ranking_value': 94}
2023-02-23 18:25:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://one-versus-one.com/new-rankings-data?model=1v1_index&page=2&age_min=16&age_max=40>
{'player': 'Ronald Araujo', 'rank': 19, 'team': 'Barcelona', 'ranking_value': 93}
2023-02-23 18:25:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://one-versus-one.com/new-rankings-data?model=1v1_index&page=2&age_min=16&age_max=40>
{'player': 'Jordi Alba', 'rank': 20, 'team': 'Barcelona', 'ranking_value': 93}
2023-02-23 18:25:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://one-versus-one.com/new-rankings-data?model=1v1_index&page=3&age_min=16&age_max=40>
{'player': 'Riyad Mahrez', 'rank': 21, 'team': 'Manchester City', 'ranking_value': 93}
2023-02-23 18:25:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://one-versus-one.com/new-rankings-data?model=1v1_index&page=3&age_min=16&age_max=40>
{'player': 'Martin Odegaard', 'rank': 22, 'team': 'Arsenal FC', 'ranking_value': 93}
2023-02-23 18:25:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://one-versus-one.com/new-rankings-data?model=1v1_index&page=3&age_min=16&age_max=40>
{'player': 'Khvicha Kvaratskhelia', 'rank': 23, 'team': 'Napoli', 'ranking_value': 93}
2023-02-23 18:25:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://one-versus-one.com/new-rankings-data?model=1v1_index&page=3&age_min=16&age_max=40>
{'player': 'Gabriel Martinelli', 'rank': 24, 'team': 'Arsenal FC', 'ranking_value': 93}
2023-02-23 18:25:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://one-versus-one.com/new-rankings-data?model=1v1_index&page=3&age_min=16&age_max=40>
{'player': 'Olexandr Zinchenko', 'rank': 25, 'team': 'Arsenal FC', 'ranking_value': 93}
2023-02-23 18:25:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://one-versus-one.com/new-rankings-data?model=1v1_index&page=3&age_min=16&age_max=40>
{'player': 'Luke Shaw', 'rank': 26, 'team': 'Manchester United', 'ranking_value': 93}
2023-02-23 18:25:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://one-versus-one.com/new-rankings-data?model=1v1_index&page=3&age_min=16&age_max=40>
{'player': 'Thiago Silva', 'rank': 27, 'team': 'Chelsea', 'ranking_value': 92}
2023-02-23 18:25:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://one-versus-one.com/new-rankings-data?model=1v1_index&page=3&age_min=16&age_max=40>
{'player': 'Solly March', 'rank': 28, 'team': 'Brighton and Hove Albion', 'ranking_value': 92}
2023-02-23 18:25:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://one-versus-one.com/new-rankings-data?model=1v1_index&page=3&age_min=16&age_max=40>
{'player': 'Granit Xhaka', 'rank': 29, 'team': 'Arsenal FC', 'ranking_value': 92}
2023-02-23 18:25:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://one-versus-one.com/new-rankings-data?model=1v1_index&page=3&age_min=16&age_max=40>
{'player': 'Erling Haaland', 'rank': 30, 'team': 'Manchester City', 'ranking_value': 92}
2023-02-23 18:25:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://one-versus-one.com/new-rankings-data?model=1v1_index&page=1&age_min=16&age_max=40>
{'player': 'Bukayo Saka', 'rank': 1, 'team': 'Arsenal FC', 'ranking_value': 100}
2023-02-23 18:25:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://one-versus-one.com/new-rankings-data?model=1v1_index&page=1&age_min=16&age_max=40>
{'player': 'Kevin de Bruyne', 'rank': 2, 'team': 'Manchester City', 'ranking_value': 99}
2023-02-23 18:25:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://one-versus-one.com/new-rankings-data?model=1v1_index&page=1&age_min=16&age_max=40>
{'player': 'Rodri', 'rank': 3, 'team': 'Manchester City', 'ranking_value': 99}
2023-02-23 18:25:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://one-versus-one.com/new-rankings-data?model=1v1_index&page=1&age_min=16&age_max=40>
{'player': 'Jack Grealish', 'rank': 4, 'team': 'Manchester City', 'ranking_value': 98}
2023-02-23 18:25:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://one-versus-one.com/new-rankings-data?model=1v1_index&page=1&age_min=16&age_max=40>
{'player': 'Lionel Messi', 'rank': 5, 'team': 'Paris Saint-Germain', 'ranking_value': 97}
2023-02-23 18:25:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://one-versus-one.com/new-rankings-data?model=1v1_index&page=1&age_min=16&age_max=40>
{'player': 'Joshua Kimmich', 'rank': 6, 'team': 'Bayern Munich', 'ranking_value': 96}
2023-02-23 18:25:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://one-versus-one.com/new-rankings-data?model=1v1_index&page=1&age_min=16&age_max=40>
{'player': 'Junior Neymar', 'rank': 7, 'team': 'Paris Saint-Germain', 'ranking_value': 95}
2023-02-23 18:25:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://one-versus-one.com/new-rankings-data?model=1v1_index&page=1&age_min=16&age_max=40>
{'player': 'Gabriel Jesus', 'rank': 8, 'team': 'Arsenal FC', 'ranking_value': 95}
2023-02-23 18:25:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://one-versus-one.com/new-rankings-data?model=1v1_index&page=1&age_min=16&age_max=40>
{'player': 'Jamal Musiala', 'rank': 9, 'team': 'Bayern Munich', 'ranking_value': 95}
2023-02-23 18:25:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://one-versus-one.com/new-rankings-data?model=1v1_index&page=1&age_min=16&age_max=40>
{'player': 'Alphonso Davies', 'rank': 10, 'team': 'Bayern Munich', 'ranking_value': 95}
2023-02-23 18:25:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://one-versus-one.com/new-rankings-data?model=1v1_index&page=5&age_min=16&age_max=40>
{'player': 'Christopher Nkunku', 'rank': 41, 'team': 'RB Leipzig', 'ranking_value': 91}
2023-02-23 18:25:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://one-versus-one.com/new-rankings-data?model=1v1_index&page=5&age_min=16&age_max=40>
{'player': 'Joelinton Cassio Apolinario de Lira', 'rank': 42, 'team': 'Newcastle United', 'ranking_value': 91}
2023-02-23 18:25:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://one-versus-one.com/new-rankings-data?model=1v1_index&page=5&age_min=16&age_max=40>
{'player': 'Sergio Busquets', 'rank': 43, 'team': 'Barcelona', 'ranking_value': 91}
2023-02-23 18:25:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://one-versus-one.com/new-rankings-data?model=1v1_index&page=5&age_min=16&age_max=40>
{'player': 'Ruben Dias', 'rank': 44, 'team': 'Manchester City', 'ranking_value': 91}
2023-02-23 18:25:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://one-versus-one.com/new-rankings-data?model=1v1_index&page=5&age_min=16&age_max=40>
{'player': 'Casemiro', 'rank': 45, 'team': 'Manchester United', 'ranking_value': 91}
2023-02-23 18:25:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://one-versus-one.com/new-rankings-data?model=1v1_index&page=5&age_min=16&age_max=40>
{'player': 'Benjamin Pavard', 'rank': 46, 'team': 'Bayern Munich', 'ranking_value': 91}
2023-02-23 18:25:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://one-versus-one.com/new-rankings-data?model=1v1_index&page=5&age_min=16&age_max=40>
{'player': 'Federico Valverde', 'rank': 47, 'team': 'Real Madrid', 'ranking_value': 91}
2023-02-23 18:25:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://one-versus-one.com/new-rankings-data?model=1v1_index&page=5&age_min=16&age_max=40>
{'player': 'Thomas', 'rank': 48, 'team': 'Arsenal FC', 'ranking_value': 91}
2023-02-23 18:25:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://one-versus-one.com/new-rankings-data?model=1v1_index&page=5&age_min=16&age_max=40>
{'player': 'Ousmane Dembele', 'rank': 49, 'team': 'Barcelona', 'ranking_value': 91}
2023-02-23 18:25:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://one-versus-one.com/new-rankings-data?model=1v1_index&page=5&age_min=16&age_max=40>
{'player': 'Dayotchanculle Upamecano', 'rank': 50, 'team': 'Bayern Munich', 'ranking_value': 91}
2023-02-23 18:25:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://one-versus-one.com/new-rankings-data?model=1v1_index&page=6&age_min=16&age_max=40>
{'player': 'Bernardo Silva', 'rank': 51, 'team': 'Manchester City', 'ranking_value': 91}
2023-02-23 18:25:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://one-versus-one.com/new-rankings-data?model=1v1_index&page=6&age_min=16&age_max=40>
{'player': 'Alexis Mac Allister', 'rank': 52, 'team': 'Brighton and Hove Albion', 'ranking_value': 91}
2023-02-23 18:25:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://one-versus-one.com/new-rankings-data?model=1v1_index&page=6&age_min=16&age_max=40>
{'player': 'Lisandro Martinez', 'rank': 53, 'team': 'Manchester United', 'ranking_value': 91}
2023-02-23 18:25:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://one-versus-one.com/new-rankings-data?model=1v1_index&page=6&age_min=16&age_max=40>
{'player': 'Willi Orban', 'rank': 54, 'team': 'RB Leipzig', 'ranking_value': 91}
2023-02-23 18:25:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://one-versus-one.com/new-rankings-data?model=1v1_index&page=6&age_min=16&age_max=40>
{'player': 'Moises Isaac Caicedo Corozo', 'rank': 55, 'team': 'Brighton and Hove Albion', 'ranking_value': 91}
2023-02-23 18:25:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://one-versus-one.com/new-rankings-data?model=1v1_index&page=6&age_min=16&age_max=40>
{'player': 'Trent Alexander Arnold', 'rank': 56, 'team': 'Liverpool FC', 'ranking_value': 91}
2023-02-23 18:25:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://one-versus-one.com/new-rankings-data?model=1v1_index&page=6&age_min=16&age_max=40>
{'player': 'Miguel Angel Almiron Rejala', 'rank': 57, 'team': 'Newcastle United', 'ranking_value': 91}
2023-02-23 18:25:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://one-versus-one.com/new-rankings-data?model=1v1_index&page=6&age_min=16&age_max=40>
{'player': 'Pervis Josue Estupinan Tenorio', 'rank': 58, 'team': 'Brighton and Hove Albion', 'ranking_value': 91}
2023-02-23 18:25:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://one-versus-one.com/new-rankings-data?model=1v1_index&page=6&age_min=16&age_max=40>
{'player': 'Mohamed Salah', 'rank': 59, 'team': 'Liverpool FC', 'ranking_value': 91}
2023-02-23 18:25:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://one-versus-one.com/new-rankings-data?model=1v1_index&page=6&age_min=16&age_max=40>
{'player': 'Nathan Ake', 'rank': 60, 'team': 'Manchester City', 'ranking_value': 91}
2023-02-23 18:25:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://one-versus-one.com/new-rankings-data?model=1v1_index&page=4&age_min=16&age_max=40>
{'player': 'Andreas Christensen', 'rank': 31, 'team': 'Barcelona', 'ranking_value': 92}
2023-02-23 18:25:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://one-versus-one.com/new-rankings-data?model=1v1_index&page=4&age_min=16&age_max=40>
{'player': 'William Saliba', 'rank': 32, 'team': 'Arsenal FC', 'ranking_value': 92}
2023-02-23 18:25:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://one-versus-one.com/new-rankings-data?model=1v1_index&page=4&age_min=16&age_max=40>
{'player': 'Harry Kane', 'rank': 33, 'team': 'Tottenham Hotspur', 'ranking_value': 92}
2023-02-23 18:25:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://one-versus-one.com/new-rankings-data?model=1v1_index&page=4&age_min=16&age_max=40>
{'player': 'Min-Jae Kim', 'rank': 34, 'team': 'Napoli', 'ranking_value': 92}
2023-02-23 18:25:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://one-versus-one.com/new-rankings-data?model=1v1_index&page=4&age_min=16&age_max=40>
{'player': 'Kieran Trippier', 'rank': 35, 'team': 'Newcastle United', 'ranking_value': 92}
2023-02-23 18:25:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://one-versus-one.com/new-rankings-data?model=1v1_index&page=4&age_min=16&age_max=40>
{'player': 'Paulo Bruno Dybala', 'rank': 36, 'team': 'AS Roma', 'ranking_value': 92}
2023-02-23 18:25:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://one-versus-one.com/new-rankings-data?model=1v1_index&page=4&age_min=16&age_max=40>
{'player': 'Amir Rrahmani', 'rank': 37, 'team': 'Napoli', 'ranking_value': 92}
2023-02-23 18:25:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://one-versus-one.com/new-rankings-data?model=1v1_index&page=4&age_min=16&age_max=40>
{'player': 'Virgil van Dijk', 'rank': 38, 'team': 'Liverpool FC', 'ranking_value': 92}
2023-02-23 18:25:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://one-versus-one.com/new-rankings-data?model=1v1_index&page=4&age_min=16&age_max=40>
{'player': 'Rodrigo Bentancur', 'rank': 39, 'team': 'Tottenham Hotspur', 'ranking_value': 92}
2023-02-23 18:25:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://one-versus-one.com/new-rankings-data?model=1v1_index&page=4&age_min=16&age_max=40>
{'player': 'Achraf Hakimi', 'rank': 40, 'team': 'Paris Saint-Germain', 'ranking_value': 91}
2023-02-23 18:25:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://one-versus-one.com/new-rankings-data?model=1v1_index&page=7&age_min=16&age_max=40>
{'player': 'Fabian Schar', 'rank': 61, 'team': 'Newcastle United', 'ranking_value': 91}
2023-02-23 18:25:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://one-versus-one.com/new-rankings-data?model=1v1_index&page=7&age_min=16&age_max=40>
{'player': 'Nico Schlotterbeck', 'rank': 62, 'team': 'Borussia Dortmund', 'ranking_value': 91}
2023-02-23 18:25:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://one-versus-one.com/new-rankings-data?model=1v1_index&page=7&age_min=16&age_max=40>
{'player': 'Ilkay Gundogan', 'rank': 63, 'team': 'Manchester City', 'ranking_value': 91}
2023-02-23 18:25:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://one-versus-one.com/new-rankings-data?model=1v1_index&page=7&age_min=16&age_max=40>
{'player': 'Mario Rui Silva Duarte', 'rank': 64, 'team': 'Napoli', 'ranking_value': 91}
2023-02-23 18:25:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://one-versus-one.com/new-rankings-data?model=1v1_index&page=7&age_min=16&age_max=40>
{'player': 'Giovanni Di Lorenzo', 'rank': 65, 'team': 'Napoli', 'ranking_value': 91}
2023-02-23 18:25:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://one-versus-one.com/new-rankings-data?model=1v1_index&page=7&age_min=16&age_max=40>
{'player': 'Nuno Albertino Varela Tavares', 'rank': 66, 'team': 'Olympique de Marseille', 'ranking_value': 90}
2023-02-23 18:25:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://one-versus-one.com/new-rankings-data?model=1v1_index&page=7&age_min=16&age_max=40>
{'player': 'Robert Lewandowski', 'rank': 67, 'team': 'Barcelona', 'ranking_value': 90}
2023-02-23 18:25:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://one-versus-one.com/new-rankings-data?model=1v1_index&page=7&age_min=16&age_max=40>
{'player': 'Martin Terrier', 'rank': 68, 'team': 'Stade Rennais', 'ranking_value': 90}
2023-02-23 18:25:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://one-versus-one.com/new-rankings-data?model=1v1_index&page=7&age_min=16&age_max=40>
{'player': 'Jules Kounde', 'rank': 69, 'team': 'Barcelona', 'ranking_value': 90}
2023-02-23 18:25:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://one-versus-one.com/new-rankings-data?model=1v1_index&page=7&age_min=16&age_max=40>
{'player': 'John Stones', 'rank': 70, 'team': 'Manchester City', 'ranking_value': 90}
2023-02-23 18:25:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://one-versus-one.com/new-rankings-data?model=1v1_index&page=8&age_min=16&age_max=40>
{'player': 'Bruno Guimaraes', 'rank': 71, 'team': 'Newcastle United', 'ranking_value': 90}
2023-02-23 18:25:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://one-versus-one.com/new-rankings-data?model=1v1_index&page=8&age_min=16&age_max=40>
{'player': 'Kaoru Mitoma', 'rank': 72, 'team': 'Brighton and Hove Albion', 'ranking_value': 90}
2023-02-23 18:25:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://one-versus-one.com/new-rankings-data?model=1v1_index&page=8&age_min=16&age_max=40>
{'player': 'Marcus Rashford', 'rank': 73, 'team': 'Manchester United', 'ranking_value': 90}
2023-02-23 18:25:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://one-versus-one.com/new-rankings-data?model=1v1_index&page=8&age_min=16&age_max=40>
{'player': 'Thiago Alcantara', 'rank': 74, 'team': 'Liverpool FC', 'ranking_value': 90}
2023-02-23 18:25:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://one-versus-one.com/new-rankings-data?model=1v1_index&page=8&age_min=16&age_max=40>
{'player': 'Lucas Paqueta', 'rank': 75, 'team': 'West Ham United', 'ranking_value': 90}
2023-02-23 18:25:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://one-versus-one.com/new-rankings-data?model=1v1_index&page=8&age_min=16&age_max=40>
{'player': 'Antony Matheus', 'rank': 76, 'team': 'Manchester United', 'ranking_value': 90}
2023-02-23 18:25:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://one-versus-one.com/new-rankings-data?model=1v1_index&page=8&age_min=16&age_max=40>
{'player': 'Benjamin William White', 'rank': 77, 'team': 'Arsenal FC', 'ranking_value': 90}
2023-02-23 18:25:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://one-versus-one.com/new-rankings-data?model=1v1_index&page=8&age_min=16&age_max=40>
{'player': 'Pierre Emile Hojbjerg', 'rank': 78, 'team': 'Tottenham Hotspur', 'ranking_value': 90}
2023-02-23 18:25:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://one-versus-one.com/new-rankings-data?model=1v1_index&page=8&age_min=16&age_max=40>
{'player': 'Reece James', 'rank': 79, 'team': 'Chelsea', 'ranking_value': 90}
2023-02-23 18:25:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://one-versus-one.com/new-rankings-data?model=1v1_index&page=8&age_min=16&age_max=40>
{'player': 'Luis Fernando Diaz Marulanda', 'rank': 80, 'team': 'Liverpool FC', 'ranking_value': 90}
2023-02-23 18:25:25 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://one-versus-one.com/new-rankings-data?model=1v1_index&page=9&age_min=16&age_max=40> (referer: None)
2023-02-23 18:25:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://one-versus-one.com/new-rankings-data?model=1v1_index&page=9&age_min=16&age_max=40>
{'player': 'Raphael Dias Belloli', 'rank': 81, 'team': 'Barcelona', 'ranking_value': 90}
2023-02-23 18:25:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://one-versus-one.com/new-rankings-data?model=1v1_index&page=9&age_min=16&age_max=40>
{'player': 'Kylian Mbappe', 'rank': 82, 'team': 'Paris Saint-Germain', 'ranking_value': 90}
2023-02-23 18:25:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://one-versus-one.com/new-rankings-data?model=1v1_index&page=9&age_min=16&age_max=40>
{'player': 'Adrien Rabiot', 'rank': 83, 'team': 'Juventus', 'ranking_value': 89}
2023-02-23 18:25:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://one-versus-one.com/new-rankings-data?model=1v1_index&page=9&age_min=16&age_max=40>
{'player': 'Marco Verratti', 'rank': 84, 'team': 'Paris Saint-Germain', 'ranking_value': 89}
2023-02-23 18:25:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://one-versus-one.com/new-r
```